# Possible false positive from [-Wdangling-reference] using g++

Tags: c++, g++, std-ranges

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> a{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  
  std::span<const int> b{ a };

  for ( auto i : b | std::views::drop(1) )
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Compiling it with `-Wextra`, g++ 13.2 (or 13.1) emits this warning:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:11:40: warning: possibly dangling reference to a temporary [-Wdangling-reference]
   11 |   for ( auto i : b | std::views::drop(1) )
      |                                        ^
<source>:11:40: note: the temporary was destroyed at the end of the full expression 'std::ranges::views::__adaptor::operator|<_Partial<std::ranges::views::_Drop, int>, std::span<const int>&>(b, ((const std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptor<std::ranges::views::_Drop>*)(& std::ranges::views::drop))->std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptor<std::ranges::views::_Drop>::operator()<int>(1))'
```

Other compilers and previous versions of g++ don't complain (see e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/Pf9YoWv57).

Is this a false positive or am I missing something?

Comment: I think that's possibly a bug of gcc...

Comment: It should be a bug, GCC-13 will not warn.

Answer (score 1):

A [range-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is *roughly* equivalent to the following:

```
{
    <init-statement>
    auto && __range = <range-expression> ;
    auto __begin = <begin-expr> ;
    auto __end = <end-expr> ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin)
    {
        <range-declaration> = *__begin;
        <loop-statement>
    }
}
```

In your case, `<range-expression>` is `b | std::views::drop(1)`, which returns a temporary object, which the loop is then taking a reference to.  A `range-for` loop will extend the lifetime of any temporary object returned by the `<range-expression>` until the end of the loop, however depending on the C++ version and compiler you are using, the loop may or may not extend the lifetime of any intermediate temporaries created inside the `<range-expression>`.  So taking a reference to the returned object may or may not indeed lead to a dangling reference.

That is what the compiler is warning you about.  See [Temporary range expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for#Temporary_range_expression) for more details.

Comment: So, the code I posted has UB (which I find quite baffling, to be honest) and it should have been written as something like `for (auto c{ b | std::views::drop(1) }; auto i : c )`. Is it correct?

Comment: No, there is no UB. This is a false positive that's cheesing off a lot of people. There were multiple bugs opened in gcc's bugzilla against the dangling-reference false positive warning, that were initially EWONTFIX then EDUPE. I had to sprinkle a liberal helping of `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdangling-reference"` in order to shut this annoying thing up.

Comment: What Remy was explaining are theoretical situations where there would be a dangling reference, in a vaguely similar situation. But there is no dangling reference in this case, obviously. The TLDR after plowing my way through gcc's bugzilla is if: 1) a function returns a reference, 2) one of the parameters is the same reference, and 3) a call shoves a temporary in there and grabs the returned reference, gcc will bleat at the call site, in morbid fear of the function returning the reference to a temporary ***without looking at the function's logic***. This is not helpful.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Now, [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111410#c0) has also been added to the pile.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in the implementation of the `-Wdangling-reference` diagnostic in GCC 13.

While 康桓瑋 ([user 康桓瑋](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11638718/%e5%ba%b7%e6%a1%93%e7%91%8b), I guess) opened a bug report ([111410](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111410#c0)), I found this comment by Marek Polacek, in a seemingly related report [[PR C++/109642]](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109642#c7):

> c++: Move `-Wdangling-reference` to `-Wextra` [[PR109642]](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109642)
>
> Sadly, `-Wdangling-reference` generates false positives for `std::span`-like
> user classes, and it seems imprudent to attempt to improve the heuristic
> in GCC 13.  Let's move the warning to `-Wextra`, that will hopefully
> reduce the number of false positives the users have been seeing with 13.
>
> I'm leaving the warning in `-Wall` in 14 where I think I can write code
> to detect `std::span-like` classes.
>
> [PR c++/109642](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109642)
> [PR c++/109640](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109640)
> [PR c++/109671](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109671)